# MongoDB Stitch iOS: Pagination with skip in collection.find()

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I am attempting to implement pagination using MongoDB Stitch in Swift for iOS, but I do not see `skip` in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/actions/collection.find/).

The `RemoteFindOptions` has sort and limit but no skip like so:

```
{
   "projection": <document>,
   "sort": <document>,
   "limit": <integer>
}
```

Is there no way to implement `skip` with mongodb stitch for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there no way to implement skip with mongodb stitch for iOS?

For pagination, you could create a [Stitch Function](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/) that returns a limited number of result using `limit`.

Essentially performing an operation similar to below:

```
db.collection.find({ "_id": 100 })
    .sort({ _id: 1 })
    .limit(50)
```

The example snippet above shows an example pagination of 50. On the client side, make sure to record the last `_id`, so that you can perform another pagination request. i.e.

```
db.collection.find({ "_id": 150 })
    .sort({ _id: 1 })
    .limit(50)
```

See also:

- [Blog: Pagination With Bucket Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1)
- [cursor.skip(): Pagination Using Range Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#using-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` instead of `find`. For example:

```
myCollection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
    { $skip: 10 },
    { $limit: 10 }
]).toArray()
```